# Duplicated files in private folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I want to put some files (CSVs) in private folder but not all files are copied to build's assets folder, because some CSVs are duplicated (and I want them to be duplicated). Is there a possibility to build all my assets?

Answer (score 0):

The build process checks the usage of each asset in your app and tries only to copy those which are in use. I would suggest you to create a package and place your csv's as you like. For each one you can create an addFile() entry so that everything is in place.